# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error yet the POST goes through anyway

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I have this JavaScript function, that does a simple jQuery AJAX() request:

```
function impLeads() {

    var go_health_id = $(".sync-action").data("subscriber");
    var customer_number = $(".sync-action").data("customer-number");
    var lead_type = $(".sync-action").data("lead-type");

    var person = {
        lead_type: lead_type,
        customer_number: customer_number,
        subscriber_id: go_health_id,
        first_name: "Daniel",
        last_name: "Endo",
        phone: "(937) 555-5555"
    }

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    data: person,
    url: "https://www.brokeroffice.com/leads/leadImport.do",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
            $(".debug").show().html(html);
            console.log('Leads imported for ' + go_health_id);
        }
    });
}
```

Now... this is a HTTP post to BrokerOffice.com. Lead data can be imported to BrokerOffice via HTTP POST. The Endpoint URL = `https://www.brokeroffice.com/leads/leadImport.do`. I am executing this script from `http://mycompanysite.com/leads/`. Notice that they have `https://` and `www` while mine do not.

**However**, when I go into BrokerOffice.com, I see that the lead was successfully posted into their database so... despite this warning:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.brokeroffice.com/leads/leadImport.do. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mycompanysite.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

The request went through.

The problem is that I have to this request on loop more than once so that JavaScript error will stop the loop from continuing the execution.

What can I do?

Comment: Regarding "despite this warning... it went through": The same-origin policy prevents your script from *reading* cross-origin *responses*; it does not stop your browser from *sending* cross-origin *requests*.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I have to this request on loop more than once so that JavaScript error will stop the loop from continuing the execution." Do you mean you *want* this request to run more than once, or you *are* running this more than once (and don't want to) in order to make it work?

Comment: @apsillers I want to run this on a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That header just stops you from being able to see a response from the server (not from sending a request).

> The problem is that I have to this request on loop more than once so
>   that JavaScript error will stop the loop from continuing the
>   execution.
>
> What can I do?

What can you do? The response header from the server needs to be changed to allow cross-origin communication. If you don't have access to changing the server, then you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

As @apsillers mentioned, you can send requests and they'll get there. You just can't get responses.

If you need to read the response, you can:

1. Use a light CORS proxy like https://github.com/gr2m/CORS-Proxy on your server.
2. Use a hosted proxy like http://crossorigin.me/

Comment: Then you can just discard the error message. It's dangerous, though, because if you don't get the response, you won't be able to tell if the request was successful, i.e. if the server received the POST.

Comment: Hello, sir? Any response?